# SQL Stored Procedure comparing NVARCHAR not working as expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012-express

I have the following SQL Server 2012 Express Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Andy Armstrong
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE db_CheckLogin 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @LoginName NVARCHAR(15),
    @Password NVARCHAR(15),
    @ReturnCode UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT UserID=@ReturnCode FROM tblMemberLogin WHERE LoginName = @LoginName AND LoginPassword = @Password;
END
GO
```

I am invoking it from a .NET C# Stored procedure as follows:

```
// Create Command Interface
            SqlCommand cmdStoredProc = new SqlCommand("db_CheckLogin", objConnection);
            cmdStoredProc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // Fill The Parameters Collection Based Upon Stored Procedure.
            SqlParameter workParam = null;
            workParam = cmdStoredProc.Parameters.Add("@LoginName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);
            workParam = cmdStoredProc.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);
            // Prepare Output Parameter
            workParam = cmdStoredProc.Parameters.Add("@ReturnCode", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
            workParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            // Set Values For Our Procedure
            cmdStoredProc.Parameters["@LoginName"].Value = ctrlUsername.Text;
            cmdStoredProc.Parameters["@Password"].Value = ctrlPassword.Text;
            // Exec Procedure
            cmdStoredProc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However for some reason it is not returning the row I would expect.

The schema for tblMemberLogin is a follows:

UserID = uniqueidentifier pk,
LoginName = NVARCHAR(15)
LoginPassword = NVARCHAR(15)

I have one row in that table which has username of `myUser` and password of `passw0rd`

however running the code with that returns 0 rows. Running the stored procedure manually also does not work - where running a query like:

SELECT UserID FROM tblMemberLogin WHERE LoginName = 'myUser' AND LoginPassword = 'passw0rd' works perfectly! Please help me spot where I am going wrong.

Comment: Please don't tell us you're storing passwords in plain text :(

Comment: in the select statement you're assigning a UserID=@ReturnCode instead of @ReturnCode =UserID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be as below I guess :-

```
SELECT @ReturnCode =UserID FROM tblMemberLogin WHERE LoginName = @LoginName AND LoginPassword = @Password;
```

Comment: Yeah, Wrong order - assigning the return code (which is not set) to the field (which is not written back).